# Getting Postfix statistics on TLS/SSL usage

Tags: ssl, postfix

My Postfix mail server is set up with opportunistic TLS. Is there a way to get some statistics on how many incoming and outgoing emails actually use TLS? It would be nice to know which of the domains that my mails server talks to support and don't support TLS as well.

Comment: I want to congratulate for the question. This is particularly helpful (and was what I was looking for) in determining when to switch off old TLS protocols. I wouldn't be surprised to discover that a number of domain I exchange mail with don't support the most recent TLS version or still want to communicate in plain text

Answer (score 5):

While [`smtpd_tls_loglevel`](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_logging) enables logging of TLS information, it alone doesn't give readable statistics. The default Postfix logfile analyzer `pflogsumm` doesn't include any TLS statistics, but [`saftsumm --tls-stats`](https://metacpan.org/pod/saftsumm) (tool from  Log-Saftpresse  logfile analyzer) may provide just what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising, but I can't get it to install: `cpanm saftsumm` tells me `! Finding saftsumm () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.`

Comment: Try `perl -MCPAN -e 'install Log::Saftpresse'` as `saftsumm` is part of Saftpresse module.

Comment: Also `cpanm -i Log::Saftpresse`, if you prefer `cpanm`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Now to wait for some logs to analyze...

Comment: OK, so I tried it, and it does show some nice stats, but nothing related to TLS/SSL. (Yes, I'm using the `--tls-stats` option.)

Answer (score 2):

The loglevel [`smtpd_tls_loglevel`](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_logging) is  0 by default, setting it to 1 should log basic TLS information.